# Doubt in tibshirani elements of statistical learning book

Tags: statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference

i am self studying the elements of statistical learning book, in chapter 2 there is this section [link to book page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn4l3.png) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn4l3.png)

and i just dont get it. How does the author replace the integral with expectation and then conclude that it is sufficient to minimize the function point wise[[link to second book page][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy4yR.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy4yR.jpg) also later he does the same for the categorical problem as well.

I dont understand these derivations and if someone could show how to do it and also if there are some general principles i should keep in mind when confronted by such terminology or derivations it would be really helpful as i am not a maths major and have never been very comfortable with these kind of things and have always been confounded by such leaps

Comment: I think the intuition for the first part is that integrating over both $X$ and $Y$ (as is being done in $2.10)$ is the same thing as integrating over just $Y$ where we hold $X$ as constant (taking it as a given, and using conditional distribution), and *then* integrating over $X$. That's basically all that's happening in $(2.11)$. You can take a step back and unfold the expectation on $X$ to see that $\int \mathbb{E}_{Y|x}([Y-f(x)]^2|x)  \mathrm{Pr}(dx) = \mathbb{E}_X \mathbb{E}_{Y|X}([Y-f(X)]^2|X)$ as an intermediate step. The author's footnote explains this, basically.

Comment: ok yeah that makes sense but how do we replace the small x with the large X. Also to separate out the joint distributions into two separate x and y, do we have to make an independence assumption to do that

Comment: For any function $f(X)$ on a random variable $X$, we always say that $\mathbb{E}_X[f(X)] = \int f(x) \mathrm{Pr}(dx)$. The difference is that $X$ is the random variable whereas $x$ is just the dummy variable in the integration that stands in for every possible value that we could consider $X$ taking on. I don’t know if that explanation helps, at all. Good luck!

Comment: ok yeah thanks that does clear up things sorry for my noobie doubts but how does the author say that it is sufficient to minimize the function point wise and then how does he get the final form of the f(x)

Comment: and for the other part of your second last comment, nah, independence would give us a stronger result. We’re saying $\mathrm{Pr}(X,Y) = \mathrm{Pr}(Y|X)\mathrm{Pr}(X)$. This is just regular old conditional probability. If we had independence, then we *could* further simplify this with $\mathrm{Pr}(Y|X) = \mathrm{Pr}(Y)$, but we don’t use that here.

Comment: honestly, I have no idea about the pointwise minimisation. I don’t really get the context of what the author is trying to achieve in this section, is he just trying to find the $f$ that minimises the EPE? I might have a look at this again tomorrow after a good sleep if you are still having trouble

Comment: ok yes you are right about that i think the author is indeed trying to find the form of f that minimizes EPE but maybe because the function is defined over all discrete points that are in the X vector thats why he says pointwise but id like to be sure